# General-purpose, open-source, GUI relational database management application

Tags: linux, open-source, database, gui

I'm looking for a general-purpose, open-source, graphical user interface database management and manipulation application for Linux. I've been using Navicat Premium Essentials on my Mac, and am in search for a similar Linux tool.

Requirements:

- open-source/Linux support, preferably in default Debian repository
- broad DBMS support (PostgreSQL, MySQL, MariaDB are mandatory; MS SQL Server and Oracle nice to have)
- remote connection capability with SSH tunnels
- viewing and altering data in tables
- query editor with some syntax highlighting

UML/ER-diagram (or similar graphical representation) export would be nice to have, but not mandatory.

There is quite a bunch of similar questions on Stack Overflow and Server Fault, but they all got closed some years ago for being off-topic and thus not rather up to date ([[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001710/what-is-the-best-free-sql-gui-for-linux-for-various-dbms-systems), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721852/developer-tools-to-directly-access-databases), [[3]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8155/mysql-gui-tools), [[4]](https://superuser.com/questions/37850/linux-gui-database-manager), [[5]](https://serverfault.com/questions/11315/any-good-postgresql-client-for-linux), ...).

Comment: Just came here to ask basically the same question. I've been trying to see if I can get MySQL Workbench to do this, but so far I can't figure out how to use it to make customized data entry forms and queries.

Comment: I don't understand the ssh-tunnel part. You can use ssh-tunnels to create a local port to remote port connection and then connect to your local machine port as if it were on the other side. How does this program need to "support" this?

Comment: Convenience and laziness. Sure I could create them on my own, but I'd prefer the client application to do this for me.

Comment: have you tried LibreOffice Base?

Comment: Libre Office Base was already proposed in the answer below -- it lacks configurable SSH-tunneling, though (so you have to open the tunnel manually).

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that springs to mind here is LibreOffice Base, in terms of multi-database support. It's free and open source, available in all (as far as I'm aware) Linux repos, has a query editor, and you can view and edit tables and data.

The only thing I am unsure of here is SSH tunnelling - it certainly can connect to remote databases, but I've only ever tinkered with that through ODBC and JDBC rather than via SSH. My instinct here is that it would be possible, but not without some modification. One method I can see would be to mount your settings in an SSHFS (SSH filesystem - using Fuse) or NFS connecting to the server with your databases.